# Meaning of "around as" and just "as"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, as

What is the difference between

> It was as big around as a truck wheel.

and

> It was as big as a truck wheel.

Comment: I couldn't make sense of your sentences, so I edited them. I might've guessed them wrong. Please feel free to edit them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good question, Dmitry! I've looked around the interwebs and found this definition:

> **[Around](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/around):** *(chiefly US)* — used to indicate a measurement that is made along the outer surface of something circular.
>
> “How big around is the tree?” “It's five feet *around*.” [=(chiefly
> Brit) *round*] [=the circumference of the tree is five feet]

So, by saying

> It was as big *around* as a truck wheel.

we are stressing the fact that this *something* is round or roughly round in one of its sections.

I've met *around* being used in this way before, and used to imagine a person circling his arms *around* something to take stock of its girth.

There is [a very good poem](http://poetry.about.com/od/poems/l/blfrostmudtime.htm) I know that applies this word in this sense, adding to the imagery:

> Good blocks of beech it was I split,
>
> As large *around as* the chopping block;
>
> And every piece I squarely hit
>
> Fell splinterless as a cloven rock.
>
> The blows that a life of self-control
>
> Spares to strike for the common good,
>
> That day, giving a loose to my soul,
>
> I spent on the unimportant wood.

Note that the blocks of beech could be much thinner than the chopping block, but they are as large *around* as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the thanks, @DmitryFucintv! By the way, it's "I've looked for" (I *have* looked for). But probably the best choice is "I have been looking for".

Comment: +1 Exactly. Something *as big as a truck wheel* is of the same size as a wheel in all dimensions; something *as big **around** as a truck wheel* is of the same size in only two dimensions.